# Where to find Saiku Reporting standalone version?

Tags: pentaho, saiku

As I understand it, currently Saiku Reporting is available (?) as a Pentaho plugin to run on any recent Pentaho BI server. But I remember that earlier was available standalone version that allows to embed Saiku Reporting into 3rd party apps.

As standalone and as plugin available only Saiku Analytics.

Saiku Analytics as Pentaho plugin:

[image]

[image]

Saiku Analytics standalone (deployed in Tomcat):

[image]

As a plugin Saiku Reporting is not available (is not ready yet), so I want to deploy Saiku Reporting standalone version in a servlet container Tomcat.

[About Saiku Reporting](https://github.com/Mgiepz/saiku-adhoc/wiki/1.-About-Saiku-Reporting)

> Saiku Reporting is a web-based reporting client available both as a
>   standalone web-application and as a plugin for the Pentaho Bi-Server.
>   It uses the Pentaho Metadata-Layer to provide an easy to use adhoc
>   reporting facility with a rich enduser experience.

Where to find Saiku Reporting standalone version?

I tried to find this version but not found.

Comment: Coming Q1 2016, Saiku Reporting will allow you to create highly customisable reports using the --same web interface-- you've become accustomed to using whilst using Saiku Analytics that are suitable to publishing and distribution..
i read somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, now I use Pentaho 4.8 as a container for Saiku Reporting plugin and Saiku Analytics as standalone web- application deployed in Tomcat. I stopped Pentaho 5 and don't see the reason to use it in my case.

[image]

Unfortunately (while, I hope) don't work filters in Saiku Reporting, I asked a separate question here - [Is there comparison predicates in Saiku Reporting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38898069/filtering-not-working)